# How to get value at a memory address in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, memory

I know that we can get the value at a memory address through a C program or gdb.

Is there any way to get it by bash shell or something like "one-line" perl instruction?

Comment: What process are you trying to read memory from? Memory addresses aren't global.

Comment: Kernel memory? Physical memory? Virtual memory? (*Whose* virtual memory?)

Comment: You might want a tool like [LIME](https://github.com/504ensicslabs/lime) if your goal is a full-system memory dump you can analyze with tools like [Volatility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(memory_forensics)).

Comment: (By contrast, if you want to expose internal variables in a C program for external inspection, there are better ways to do that -- I've even seen a tiny embedded web server built for the purpose).

Comment: I'd love to know what the *close* flags are for.  I don't see this is obvious in any manual I'd have expected the OP to have read.  I haven't found a duplicate on SO.  There is nothing wrong with asking a question to which the answer is *"you can't and / or you shouldn't"*.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, "too broad". Which it is. Doesn't specify what kind of memory one wishes to inspect, doesn't imply anything useful about context that could be used to narrow a solution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how is it broad?  It's asking for a relatively specific capability in a specified language.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, no, it's not a specific *at all*. See the questions I asked in [my prior comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757960/how-to-get-value-at-a-memory-address-in-linux-shell/47758478?noredirect=1#comment82480582_47757960). The question should include answers to all of those to allow a complete and canonical answer (and determination of which kinds of memory dumps are and are not responsive).

Comment: @PhilipCouling, ...if the OP wants to collect "all of those" (from what I got from your now-deleted comment), then they want to use something like LIME (to get the whole system's physical memory and the map of that into per-process virtual memory). If their code is running in a qemu/kvm virtual machine, they can do even better, getting a fully consistent dump from the virtualization platform... but that's yet another not-included detail.

Comment: Yes, there's a level of knowledge needed to ask a good question. Just like we don't let people post a homework assignment without figuring out enough on their own to at least show a specific implementation that has a specific problem they're able to describe and isolate, someone who asks how to dump memory without even knowing what kinds of memory there are that one could potentially dump is at a place where they need to do more research and come back with a better question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah. I think you're getting into the territory of expecting the OP to know the answer to their own question before they post.  The answer to all of the above is "cant / dont".  If the answer to you're queries changes the answer you wish to give then there's nothing wrong with giving a multipart answer.  If the Op knew the answer to your clarification, then the chances he wouldn't have needed to ask it.

Comment: The "nothing wrong with giving a multipart answer" approach gets us into the space of [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal), answers for which need to change as the question is clarified. Requesting a clear question up-front (as by closing down an unclear or overbroad initial query until it's edited into or re-asked as a specific question amenable to a complete and canonical answer) avoids trouble down the line. But maybe I've been here long enough to get jaded. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I don't disagree about a general doing research. I'm at a loss to understand what you expect an OP with this knowledge base to have typed into google which would have given sufficient knowledge to "ask a good question".  From their standpoint (and that of future readers) there just isn't a good connection to get from this question (in the OP's mind) to a google search which would lead them anywhere near the points you want them to have researched before hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160969/discussion-between-philip-couling-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer... No

If you were very careful it MIGHT be possible to pass instructions into GDB and interpret the output.  Look at rocky's answer if you want to try.

Its part of the unix process model that one process cannot see inside another and cannot read each other's memory.  This is for security.  There is a special kernal API which can be used to see into programs.  But there are very few clients for this API.  Off the top of my head GDB is the only one I know.

**I suspect that what you're trying to achieve is either a really bad idea or can be done without reading a program's memory.**

Comment: Eh? gdb absolutely can be told to attach to a given process as part of a scripted operation.

Comment: yes of course it can.  regular processes can't.  There's a sepcial API for it.  thought I'd made that clear.  For more information on why GDB can but otherwise processes can't... see here https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8531/why-how-is-gdb-allowed-to-attach-to-a-process-and-read-write-to-attached-process

Comment: I'm well aware of the ptrace syscall. Your original answer implied that only programs compiled with debug info could be attached to, which is false, and said "I don't believe [it's] designed that way" with respect to gdb being easily scriptable; it's that implication that gdb could not be *easily* scripted that my prior comment was in response to.

Comment: (Actually, the "debug-compiled programs" qualification in this answer means it *still* implies that only programs with debug symbols can be attached to, which remains false).

Comment: True that's a little misleading in the way I worded it. I've edited that to adjust.  The main point still remains.  **"Cant / Shouldn't"**.  There's increasingly strong limitations preventing processes from doing it.  Automating it in bash suggests it's being done for something other than debug which is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

The following possibly gets close to what you may want. And if not, hopefully you'll be able to adapt.

I'll say at the outset though that you are extremely vague at what you mean by "memory address". Below I am going to take that to mean the address of the current instruction executed which I will use the gdb command "backtrace" to get. Adapt the gdb command from "bt" to whatever it is you were thinking of to get the "memory address".

Let's say your program is sleeper-for-pid with process id 3963

```
 sudo gdb --ex 'bt 1' --batch -nx -p 3963
```

will run gdb attached to the process and give a backtrace of the most recent  entry. Here is an example:

```
sudo gdb --ex 'bt 1' --batch -nx -p 3963
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) #0  0x00007f5dee71f2f0 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
```

If you really just want the line with the address, you'd grep for `#0`, e.g.

```
sudo gdb --ex 'bt 1' --batch -nx -p 3963 | grep '#0'
(gdb) #0  0x00007f5dee71f2f0 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
```

And if you just want the address you might have to do a further cut, e.g.

```
$ sudo gdb --ex 'bt 1' -nx -p 3963| grep '#0' | cut -d' ' -f 4
0x00007f5dee71f2f0
```

If you don't know the process id, you might be able to use `pidof`. For example if the command name is `sleeper-for-pid`:

```
$ sudo gdb --ex 'bt 1' --batch -nx -p $(pidof sleeper-for-pid)
```

And "sudo" may or may not work for you or be needed.

Personally, instead of just the most recent backtrace entry I prefer more than that. So `bt 1` might get adjusted to `bt 3` or `bt` for a more full back trace.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started .

Answer (score 0):

> I know that we can get the value at a memory address through a C program or gdb Are there any way to get it by bash shell or something like "one-line" perl instruction??

A shell is just a program. What you asking to do is rather meaningless. Assuming a shell did allow you to inspect a memory address (and you could easily modify a shell or write your own to do so), The value of a memory address is for the shell's process. Any other process is going to have a different memory value at the same address.

Comment: No need to modify a shell's source, even -- bash supports loadable modules written in C that add new built-in commands. One could certainly add peek and poke support for that shell's own address space quite easily.